# Is the statement $P \longrightarrow Q$ vacuously true or undefined when $P$ is false but $Q$ is undefined?

Tags: logic, induction

I know that $P \longrightarrow Q$ is vacuously true if $P$ is false. I wonder is it still true when $Q$ is an undefined or ill-formed statement.

For example, is this statement vacuously true, or is it just ill-formed?
$$
1=0 \longrightarrow \frac{1}{0} = 0
$$

On the other hand, is this statement vacuously true?
$$
\frac{1}{0} = 0 \longrightarrow 1=0
$$

I begin to wonder this when I am reviewing the mathematical induction. It says that for a property $P(n)$ pertaining to all natural numbers, if $P(0)$ and $P(n) \longrightarrow P(n+1)$, then $P$ is always true.

For a property $P$ that is undefined for $0$, I see that people often refer $P(0)$ as vacuously true when applying mathematical induction. I think that this is not the case.

An example:

> Prove that for a set $X$ that contains $n$ real numbers, there exists a real number $M$ such that $\forall x \in X, x \leq M$

> Proof: Use induction on $n$. When $n = 0$, then case is **vacuously true (or meaningless)**. Then the basic case becomes when $n=1$. Then let $x$ be the only element in $X$, and let $M$ be $x$ itself, then on this case the statement is true. Now suppose that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the statement is already true. When $X$ contains $k+1$ elements, we use $X$ as $(X\setminus\{a\}) \cup \{a\}$. The set $X\setminus\{a\}$ has $k$ elements, and we denote the number as $M$. $a$ either $\geq$ or $<$ $M$. On the former case, let $M'=a$, and on the latter case, let $M'=M$. Then $M'$ is the number we want. We can now close the induction.

Comment: Usually in the case of mathematical induction $P(0)$ is not undefined. You should give an explicit example of this, so we can give a better explanation.

Comment: @Trebor I have added an example.

Comment: @Taylor_Graph In your case $P(0)$ is very well defined. $\forall x \in \varnothing, A$ is always defined and always true. And **vacuously true** refers exclusively to this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being undefined/nonsensical/**meaningless is different from vacuously true**, and your textbook's attempt to conflate the two is poor practice.

Being undefined is infectious.  Any statement, part of which is undefined, is itself undefined.  For example: $\frac{1}{0}$ is an undefined notation, so equation $\frac{1}{0}=1$ has no well-defined truth value.  $\frac{1}{0}=1$ is undefined, so $${\frac{1}{0}=1}\to{0=1}$$ is too.

**A statement that is vacuously true is a statement that is true by convention.**  Almost always, this means a statement that depends on a variable, but for which there are no valid values for that variable.  For example, the statement "any $x$ such that $x\cdot0=1$ satisfies $x=1$" is vacuously true, because there are no such $x$.

There's no *a priori* reason to define such statements to be true, except that it makes a lot of proofs easier.  For example: consider the statement "Given an integer $y$, let $x$ be a positive integer less than $y$.  Any prime factor of $x$ is less than $y$ too."  When $y=5$, this statement is true (exercise!).  When $y=-5$, this statement is *still* true; there are no such $x$, and our vacuousness convention steps in.  This means that any proof of our statement doesn't have to worry about whether $y$ is positive.

**In the example you cite from your textbook,** when $n=0$, the claim is that "There exists a real number $M$ such that, for any $x\in X$ (where $|X|=0$), we have $x<M$."  There are no such $x$, so our vacuousness convention makes the claim true.

Comment: I still have a question. Suppose we encounter a property that is really undefined for $n=0$ (e.g. A function $f$ is defined for $n\geq 1$, and the property states that $f(n) = \dots$), then is it by convention that we start mathematical induction at $n=1$?

Comment: Sort of?  You can start induction at any point.  (But then your proof doesn't apply to numbers lower than where you started, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question in this query's title, I would say that it is (vacuously) true.  This is because
$P \rightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to 
$[E_1] \;$ (Not $P$) or $Q$.

I was taught that $E_1$ was automatically true whenever $P$ was false.

**However,** my teaching may have contained the (unspoken) assumption that $E_1$ only has meaning when $Q$ is a statement that is either true or false.

If, in contrast, $Q$ is a *meaningless* statement that is neither true nor false, (and assuming that $P$ is false), then it is unclear to me whether $E_1$ is meaningful.

An example of a (meaningless) statement that is neither true nor false is: 
37 is bigger than an orange.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of vacuous truth states that for **any logical propositions** $A$ and $B$ (whether they are true or false), we have the tautology:

> $A \implies (\neg A \implies B)$

Here is the truth table:

[image]

If $A$ is true (lines 1 and 2), then the implication $\neg A \implies B$ (column 5) is vacuously true whether $B$ is true or false (lines 1 and 2 resp.).

Here is a formal proof using a form of natural deduction:

[image]